# How to restore the old version of the report in JasperReports Server after replacing it with another one using iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have an iReport Designer which is connected to a remote JasperReports Server. I develop reports locally and upload them to the server using iReport. If I updated anything I just right click on the report from Repository Navigator and choose replace with current document, unfortunately I replaced a wrong report with my current document, so is there any way to restore the old report. Can it be found anywhere on the server?

Answer (score 2):

There is no version history in the JasperServer repository. What I do in development is keep a git (or svn) repository, and commit each jrxml modification prior to uploading it to the repository.